# Datastax 5.0.5 INFO [PO-thread-0] DbInfoRollupPlugin.java - Error retrieving node level db summary

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0

I'm running DSE 5.0.5 on 2 identical clusters, all nodes being Spark+SOLR.  On the first everything is ok, however on the second I got this message in /var/lib/cassandra/system.log:

```
INFO  [PO-thread-0] 2017-04-02 19:26:43,176  DbInfoRollupPlugin.java:196 - Error retrieving node level db summary
```

It is reported as "INFO" however something is wrong and I can't figure it out. Partial stack trace follows:

```
INFO  [PO-thread-0] 2017-04-02 19:26:43,176  DbInfoRollupPlugin.java:196 - Error retrieving node level db summary
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at com.datastax.bdp.plugin.DeferringScheduler$DeferringTask.get(DeferringScheduler.java:115) ~[dse-core-5.0.5.jar:5.0.5]
    at com.datastax.bdp.reporting.snapshots.db.DbInfoRollupPlugin$DbInfoRollupTask.doRollup(DbInfoRollupPlugin.java:192) [dse-core-5.0.5.jar:5.0.5]
    at com.datastax.bdp.reporting.snapshots.db.DbInfoRollupPlugin$DbInfoRollupTask.run(DbInfoRollupPlugin.java:173) [dse-core-5.0.5.jar:5.0.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_112]
```

Could you please indicate what to check to correct this issue.
Many Thanks

I figured out that is this property:

dse.db_info_rollup_node_query_timeout that has a default of 3000 ms.

However I don't know where to set it...

Pls advice,

Thx.,

Cristian

Comment: What do you see in the logs on the other nodes at the same time the trace is from?

Answer (score 0):

Please set `performance_core_threads: 2` in `dse.yaml`. Note that this setting is probably missing in default `dse.yaml` so you will have to add it. Don't confuse it with

Although you receive that timeout exception, it should work.